# Running X applications on local display from remote host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11

This is making me frustrated. Why doesn't it work, and how do I get it to work?

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 10.04.2 (Lucid Lynx). I have installed X and gdm. Gdm is set up to automatically log in a user. The computer does not have any keyboard connected, but I want to display some stuff on its local display.

Normally, I would just ssh to the computer as the user who has logged in automatically, and run "DISPLAY=:0.0 xclock", for example.

But now I only get the response:

```
user@host:~$ DISPLAY=:0.0 xclock
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

However, if I log in as root, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of bugs involved in this problem:
[This one](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/19649)  prevents an .Xauthority file from being created. And [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/gdm/+bug/586503) prevents the proposed workaround from working when using an automatic login.

So the solution was to change the automatic login to a timed login with a short delay, and add the following to /etc/gdm/PostLogin/default

```
#!/bin/bash

auth=$HOME/.Xauthority
if [ -e $auth ]; then
diff <(xauth extract - $DISPLAY) <(XAUTHORITY=$auth xauth extract - $DISPLAY) > /dev/null && exit 0
fi
xauth extract - $DISPLAY | XAUTHORITY=$auth xauth merge -
chown $USER $auth
```

Comment: Or just run 'xhost +localhost' as the user who is logged in on the machine before starting the X client.